# PowerShell: Passing an ArrayList of Objects into another Script as an Argument

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist, scripting, arguments

I am trying to pass an ArrayList that contains objects into another PowerShell script to execute something further.

The error message that I am receiving is:

> "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'al'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashable System.Collections.Hashable System.Collections.Hashable" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.ArrayList""

In script1.ps1:

```
$al = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

...

$obj =  @{"var1"="apple"; "var2"="banana"; "var3"="carrot";}
$al.Add($obj)

...


foreach ($i in $al) {
    $temp = $($i.var1)
    write-host "$temp"     #outputs "apple" correctly
}

invoke-expression -Command "script2.ps1 -al '$al'"
```

In script2.ps1:

```
param ([System.Collections.ArrayList]$al)

...

foreach ($i in $al) {
    $temp = $($i.var1)
    write-host "$temp"     #error message
}
```

Comment: one very simple way to pass structured data between PoSh scripts is to use one of the structured data file types. JSON is the most often recommended, but the `Export/Import-CliXml` cmdlets handle PoSh data types very neatly. so i would export to a CliXml file & then have the other script import that file. that way all you need to pass is the full file name. [*grin*]

Comment: Please consider upvoting any answers you found helpful, or accepting an answer (via the checkbox) if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reason that I'm not familiar with, `Invoke-Expression` is converting your ArrayList to a HashTable. If you really need an ArrayList in script2.ps1, you can make `$al` a global variable (see below).

Updated script1.ps1

```bsh
$al = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$obj = @{"var1" = "apple"; "var2" = "banana"; "var3" = "carrot"; }
$al.Add($obj)

foreach ($i in $al) {
    $temp = $($i.var1)
    write-host "$temp"     
}

$Global:al = $al

invoke-expression -Command "$PSScriptRoot\script2.ps1"
```

Updated script2.ps1

```bsh
param()

$Global:al.GetType().FullName

foreach ($i in $Global:al) {
    $temp = $($i.var1)
    write-host "$temp"     
}
```

Comment: `$obj` is creating a hashtable that he is adding to his ArrayList.

Comment: @Ash, `$al` still an still an ArrayList when used by `Invoke-Expression`. This can verify this by adding `$al.GetType().FullName` to the line before the one where script2.ps1` is invoked.

Comment: He's then converting it to a string by wrapping the variable in quotes, which is causing the problem. In reality it works. I think you still need to choose whether you need a key/value pairing such as a hashtable or dictionary, or a List/Array of objects. I'm not sure a list of hashtables is particularly helpful.